# ¿Como puedo imprimir cuántos alumnos aprobaron y cuántos reprobaron en C?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio: Queremos almacenar en una matriz las notas de informática de los alumnos de secundaria de una escuela. Suponiendo que hay 4 grados distintos, 15 alumnos por grado.

Y uno de los puntos que tengo que hacer es lo siguiente:

Imprimir cuántos alumnos aprobaron y cuántos reprobaron de cada grado. (para aprobar tiene que sacar mas de 4)

Abajo de todo esta el intento, donde el resultado no imprime lo que busco.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int vector[4][15];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int tgra[15]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int tnota[4]= {0,0,0,0};
int may=-9999;
int notamasalta=0;
int aprobado[2] = {0,0};
int desaprobado[2] = {0,0};

// Ingresar las notas por grado e imprimir.
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<15; j++)
    {
        printf("ingrese la nota del %d%c alumno del %d %cgrado: ",j+1,248,i+1,248);
        scanf("%d",&vector[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<15; j++)
    {
        printf("El %d%c alumno del %d%c saco: %d",j+1,248,i+1,248,vector[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}

//Sacar promedio de las notas por grado

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<15; j++)
    {
        tgra[i]=tgra[i]+vector[i][j];
        tnota[j]=tnota[j]+vector[i][j];
    }

}

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    printf("nota promedio de %d%c grado: %d",i,248,tgra[i]/15);
    printf("\n");
}

//imprimir la mayor nota

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<15; j++)
    {
        if(vector[i][j]>may)
        {
            may = vector[i][j];
        }
    }
}
//Contar Alumnos Aprobados y Desaprobados
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<15; j++)
    {
        if(vector[i][j]>=4)
        {
            aprobado[i] = aprobado[i] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            desaprobado[i] = desaprobado[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}
//Mostrar Alumnos Aprobados y Desaprobados
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("El Numero de alumnos aprobados del grado %d son: %d",i+1,aprobado[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("El Numero de alumnos reprobados del grado %d son: %d",i+1,desaprobado[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende donde tenes el problema. En general en las preguntas sobre ejercicios se pide que trates de resolverlo y digas donde tenes el problema en particular.

Comment: No entiendo la edicion, porque agregaste el codigo de la respuesta a la pregunta? tenes algun problema mas?

Comment: Intente hacerlo con el ejemplo que me dio @BadBios, pero no me salio

Comment: Que quiere decir no me salio? Y no edites la pregunta con las respuestas q te dan. Fijate como funciona el sitio, es una pregunta y una respuesta.

Comment: @Jefren no te funciona porque declaras los vectores con dimension de 2 ( aprobado[2] = {0,0}; ), se supone que son 4 grupos.

Answer (score 1):

Opino lo mismo que @gbianchi, mas no que resuelvan el ejercio.

Te recomiendo crear un vector para aprovados y otro reprobado del tamaño de los grados, asi vas acomulando los que ganaron de cada grado y perdieron de cada grado.

Debes hacer un ciclo y comparar el valor en esa posicion si es mayor o igual que 4, si es asi lo guardas en el vector de aprobados < if ( vector[i][j] >= 4) { apro[i] += 1;} >
en caso de que no lo guardas en el vector de reprbados.

> te dejo un pequeño ejemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int Grados = 2, Alumnos = 4;
    int Ganaron[2] = {0,0};
    int Perdieron[2] = {0,0};
    int vector[Grados][Alumnos];


    // Ingresar las notas por grado e imprimir.
    for( int i = 0; i < Grados; i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < Alumnos ; j++){
            printf("ingrese la nota del %d%c alumno del %d %cgrado: ",j+1,248,i+1,248);
            scanf("%d",&vector[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Numero Alumnos Perdieron y Ganaron
    for( int i = 0; i < Grados; i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < Alumnos ; j++){
            if( vector[i][j] >= 4){
                Ganaron[i] = Ganaron[i] + 1;
            }else{
                Perdieron[i] = Perdieron[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Mostrar 
    for( int i = 0; i < Grados; i++){
        printf("El Numero de alumnos aprobados del grado %d son: %d",i+1,Ganaron[i]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("El Numero de alumnos reprobados del grado %d son: %d",i+1,Perdieron[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usar VLAs cuando no está soportado por el estándar desde C99 (1999) no me parece algo adecuado.